# How to access the statement object (of each line of code) when using JDI?

Tags: java, mirror, jdi

I am writing a program to step through Java code using JDI.
I am now at the point where I can inspect the values of all the variables that I care about at any given moment.

Now, I want to be able to inspect the nature of each line of code (that is being stepped through). For example, is the program doing a comparison between two variables? is it an assignment statement?

I looked through various classes and tutorials but couldn't find *if* there's a class that presents this concept. The closest thing I found was the [Location](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/Location.html) class...but it still does not contain the information I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the exact source code line then Location will help you getting the source line that is being executed:

```
Location.lineNumber()
Location.sourceName()
```

Once you get the source line number then the source path can be read to know the exact statement that is executed. Similar to how eclipse debugger does it.

As to the nature of statement being executed is out of scope of JDI(as far as I know) and it falls more under the parsing java language statements.
Like one [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/08/parse-a-sequence-of-java-statements-by-using-jdt-astparser/)